# Websocket secured server in Python using SimpleWebSocketServer module

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to implement a websocket secure server in Python (based on [this](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server) module)
In the link, it says that the module supports TLS and SSL connections, but doesn't explain **how**.

The code I currently have goes like that:

```
from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket
import ssl

class SimpleResponder(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        self.sendMessage(self.data)

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 8000, SimpleResponder)
try:
    server.serveforever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
print "Server ended"
```

I tried to implement SSL wrapping in the same way I would do with a HTTP server (like that):

```
server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (server.socket, certfile='path/to/localhost.pem', server_side=True)
```

But seems like it doesn't work (I get the next error):

```
AttributeError: 'SimpleWebSocketServer' object has no attribute 'socket'
```

So clearly the `SimpleWebSocketServer` class isn't structured like the `SimpleHTTPServer` class.
So how **can** I implement a secure websocket server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server#tlsssl-example):

> TLS/SSL Example
>
> 1) Generate a certificate with key
>
> ```
> openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
> ```
>
> 2) Run the secure TSL/SSL server (in this case the cert.pem file is in
>   the same directory)
>
> ```
> python SimpleExampleServer.py --example chat --ssl 1 --cert ./cert.pem
> ```
>
> 3) Offer the certificate to the browser by serving websocket.html
>   through https. The HTTPS server will look for cert.pem in the local
>   directory. Ensure the websocket.html is also in the same directory to
>   where the server is run.
>
> ```
> sudo python SimpleHTTPSServer.py
> ```
>
> 4) Open a web browser to:
>   https://localhost:443/websocket.html
>
> 5) Change ws://localhost:8000/ to wss://localhost:8000 and click
>   connect.
>
> Note: if you are having problems connecting, ensure that the
>   certificate is added in your browser against the exception
>   https://localhost:8000 or whatever host:port pair you want to connect
>   to.

I found that [Autbahn|Python](http://autobahn.ws/python/index.html) was very easy to use. It work with both [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) and [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) networking engines.